# SQL Server update statement won't update table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a server running enterprise version of SQL Server 2012. I took a backup of the production database 2 days ago to test my migration script. It worked beautifully

The SAME database 2 days newer failed today because the first step of my process was to simply update some records.

```
 update TroopGirls 
 set gsusaid = '00000000000'+GSUSAID 
 where len(gsusaid) = 1
```

is one such statement.

Running this statement will say updated(61) records every time

I've run it inside a transaction frame with a commit, used go statements, messed with transaction isolation levels, all to no avail.

There are no locks anywhere in the database and the only process running against this database is the query window.

Right clicking the table and saying 'Edit top 200 rows' does work.  Problem is I have to update something in the range of 750k records across many tables and schemas.

Comment: Can you try a SELECT statement with the same WHERE criteria? Does that return rows?

Comment: Are you sure 'Edit top 200 rows' does work.  I bet you put in the 0000 came back and they were gone.  I bet gsusaid is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `gsusaid` is `varchar/nvarchar` column, `CONCAT` function will work for updating it.

```
update TroopGirls 
set gsusaid = CONCAT('00000000000', GSUSAID)
where len(gsusaid) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and guess that `gsusaids` is some kind of numeric datatype.  Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @t table (i int, v varchar(10));

INSERT @t values (1, '1'), (10, '10'), (100,'100');

SELECT * FROM @t
-- i   v
--======
-- 1   1
-- 10  10
-- 100 100   

SELECT LEN(i), len(v) FROM @t
-- i   v
--======
-- 1   1
-- 2   2
-- 3   3   

UPDATE @t SET i = '000' + i WHERE LEN(i) = 1
-- 1 row affected
UPDATE @t set v = '000' + v WHERE LEN(v) = 1
-- 1 row affected
UPDATE @t set i = '000' + i WHERE LEN(i) = 1
-- 1 row affected - because int doesn't keep the leading zeroes
UPDATE @t set v = '000' + v WHERE LEN(v) = 1
-- 0 rows affected - because the varchar column got updated already.

SELECT * FROM @t
-- i   v
--======
-- 1   001
-- 10  10
-- 100 100
```

In other words, unless `gsusaid` is some kind of character type, it won't keep the leading `0`s.

If you need `gsusaid` to be printed/selected with leading zeroes, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(gsusaid, '000000000000') FROM TroopGirls
```

If you need it to be stored in that format, you should make sure the datatype is a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` - but if it's actually numeric data, you're really better off keeping it numeric and letting applications/users/reports format it however they want (with whatever number of leading zeroes).  Also, changing the data type on the column **could** break other artifacts or applications.

Comment: I'm dumb.  It was totally this.